# How to display SQL dates in the last 30 days?

Tags: sql, date

I want to display the dates only in the past 30 days. for my SQL command. I have a DATETIME field called statement_to_date and I want to find all of the columns in the past 30 days for statement_to_date. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT Statement_TO_DATE, STATEMENT_FROM_DATE
  FROM claim;
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
```

I thought I could plug Statement_TO_DATE where INTERVAL is, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS in the question

Comment: Updated @GurwinderSingh

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) you can see that you're not using `DATE_ADD()` correctly.
Also like [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) said you're missing a `WHERE` clause, try:

```
SELECT Statement_TO_DATE, STATEMENT_FROM_DATE
FROM claim
WHERE statement_to_date >= DATE_ADD(day, -30, GETDATE());
```

Comment: If that is what w2schools teaches, then it is just plain wrong.

Comment: Have you tried the syntax above? The semicolon `;` after the table name `claim` is the terminator of the statement, so the `Where` clause will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `where` clause:

```
SELECT Statement_TO_DATE, STATEMENT_FROM_DATE
FROM claim
WHERE statement_to_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY);  -- assumes the value is never in the future
```

Normally, when working with timespans in dates, you don't want the time component of the current date.  So, this is more typical:

```
SELECT Statement_TO_DATE, STATEMENT_FROM_DATE
FROM claim
WHERE statement_to_date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY);
```

Note that MySQL also has `DATE_SUB()`, if you don't want a negative time interval.

Answer (score -1):

Select DATEADD(Month, -1, getdate())

Comment: If you're posting an answer, you should add some comments supporting your answer.